# Multiple Visible Pages in Scroll Style UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, ios6, uipageviewcontroller

So what I'm looking to do is have a UIPageViewController that will end up displaying three view controller vies, one fully visible and then two as previews to the right and left.  An example would be the iOS6 App Store:

[image: iOS6 App Store]

Is doing this using a UIPageViewController set to  `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll` possible?

Basically I'd ideally like to have is a case where I can have three UIViewControllers that I recycle as the user pages through the 1- items in the list (with n being at least 50). I know an interface that behaves like this can be done with a UIScrollView with paging enable, but re-using views would take some view shuffling code that I'd rather not write if Apple has already done it for me.

I'm totally comfortable with the fact that this is iOS6 only, by the way, and also comfortable with alternatives, if they exist.

Thanks!

Comment: So what did you end up with?

Comment: Basically a horizontal collection view with the scroll view set to page.  I made it not fill the whole width and had clipsToBounds turned off.  I don't have the code in front of me right now.

Comment: Sounds about right. Too bad it's not built into the PageViewController - it seems so close. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I know.  Oh well....

Comment: @ultramiraculous Can you post your code as an answer here? It will be greatly helpful to others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the new [collection view](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html). I think you may be able to create something like that with reusing cell etc.

Comment: Thanks.  This is what I eventually ended up doing when I got around to this feature.